# Doubts on using ChunkedWriteHandler to receive large data

Tags: java, netty

I am a newbie to Netty. For writing large data using Netty , I found that ChunkedWriteHandler can be used as in the below explanation :

> To use ChunkedWriteHandler in your application, you have to insert a
>   new ChunkedWriteHandler instance:

```
ChannelPipeline p = ...;
 p.addLast("streamer", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
 p.addLast("handler", new MyHandler());
```

> Once inserted, you can write a ChunkedInput so that the
>   ChunkedWriteHandler can pick it up and fetch the content of the stream
>   chunk by chunk and write the fetched chunk downstream:

```
Channel ch = ...;
 ch.write(new ChunkedFile(new File("video.mkv"));
```

I'd like to know :

1. How the file can be read at the destination? Any sample code would be really helpful.
2. Does MyHandler() have to be added to both server and client ChannelPipelines?
3. On the receiving end, should `MyHandler()` class extend  SimpleChannelInboundHandler(ChunkedFile> or is it possible by extending **SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler**